# How to run multiple simultaneous bash shells without a GUI?

Tags: java, linux, bash, centos

Is it possible to have several command prompts running simultaneously and switch between them, without using a GUI?

**Background**

I have installed CentOS-5.5-i386 without any extras, so I have a bash command prompt with root access but no GUI as far as I know.

I have written a simple Java servlet using Jetty. When I run it, it gets to a couple of commands like this;

```
server.start();
server.join();
```

where it waits for incoming requests forever - ie. it never returns to the command prompt.

I want to run a web server without the overhead of a GUI. How can I run my Java program and also continue to use the server from a command prompt?

I apologise for the waffly nature of this question but I am both a Linux newbie and a Java newbie.

Regards,

Nigel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch between consoles using Alt+F1 to Alt+F6. For more shortcuts take a look here: http://linux.about.com/od/linux101/l/blnewbie5_1.htm

Answer (score 8):

In the general case you want `screen` or `tmux`.  For running daemons, though, take a look at `nohup my-daemon &` or even just `my-daemon &`.

Comment: So my Java servlet should really be a Daemon. Thanks for the suggestions. Keywords like "nohup" and "my-daemon" to search on is exactly what I need.